# How do i record my computer screen

Tags: youtube, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best software for desktop recording?](https://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording)

i want to record my computer screen and talk over it. i have seen this done on youtube and i want to use this for my family. Are they just using a regular video recorder on a tripod?

Comment: I think it is OBS (Open Broadcaster Software).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Camstudio](http://camstudio.org/) its a free software you install and pretty easy to use

Answer (score 3):

Well actually [Camtasia Studio](http://camstudio.com) isn't free (you actually get it for 60 days) and the rendering is a bit pixelated. You should try [Microsoft Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/EncoderPro_Overview.aspx). The video recording is Super Clean and to get a free copy just register as a student on DreamSpark.